# Problems with pointers when parsing a .blend file

Tags: blend-files

I'm trying to parse .blend file produced by Blender 2.79b and having problems with some pointers refer to memory outside of data present in the file. Here are examples of some fields I'm not able to resolve:

- `wmWindowManager.queue.first`
- `wmWindowManager.queue.last`
- `wmWindowManager.reports.list.first`
- ...
- `Scene.stats`
- `Scene.sound_scene`
- `Scene.speaker_handles`
- `Scene.theDag`
- ...

Are they supposed to point at some blocks inside the file or such fields are ignored and substituted by Blender at loading phase by new instances?

The file is a default project with the cube.

Comment: I suspect these could be from an addon(s).  Do you for instance use a sound addon in 2.79?

Comment: @batFINGER no, I'm experimenting with fresh Blender installation to avoid any influence from addons or whatever else